# Wildcard generics of map() method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, option-type

This is the implementation of `map()` method:

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
    if (!isPresent()) {
        return empty();
    } else {
        return Optional.ofNullable(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

When I call `map()` like this, what is the type of `T` and `U`? What is the type of wildcard (`?`)? It is very confusing.

```
Optional<String> os1 = Optional.of("Optional String");
Optional<String> os2 = os1.map(s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

Javadoc statement says:

> @param `<U>` is the type of the value returned from the mapping function.

Does "*mapping function*" mean `map()` method or argument of the `map()`?

Comment: "_What is the type of wildcard_" - this doesn't make sense as a question, the wildcard has no type; it's a wildcard. "_mapping function_" is the `Function` called `mapper`.

Comment: The wildcard is of the type CaptureOf#T no idea how exactly this means, just search for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless if it's `Stream` or [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), the purpose of the method `map` which accepts [`Function<? super T, ? extends U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is to map each input value `T` to an output of the same or different type `U`. The wildcard is used for extending the range of mapping possibilities.

> Does "*mapping function*" mean `map()` method or argument of the `map()`?

The "*mapping function*" is a `T` -> `U` mapping implementation of an anonymous class of the `Function` interface which might be shortened with a lambda expression or a method reference.

In your sample, the `T` and `U` are both `String` since you map the `String` to its upper-case variation which is a `String` again. It behaves the same like [`UnaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) a special case of [`Function<T, T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) which consumes and returns the same type.

On the other hand, if you map:

```
os1.map(s -> s.length())
```

- The `T` is `String`
- The `U` is `Integer` since the method `String::length` produces an integer

You might shorten the lambda with a method reference:

```
Optional<String> os2 = os1.map(String::toUpperCase);
```

... or better use both of the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)s together:

```
Optional<String> os1 = Optional.of("Optional String");
                               .map(String::toUpperCase);
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, just to answer your question of:

> Does "mapping function" mean map() method or argument of the map()?

This "mapping function" refers to the argument supplied to the `map` method of the `Optional<T>` type.

To make things easier to understand, just forget about the wildcard (`?`) for a moment as we could do without its confusion and focus on the type `T` and `U`, the simplified version below:

```
public <U> Optional<U> map(Function<T, U> mapper) { ... }
```

- Where `T` represents any type of object as input and `U` represents any type as output.
- `Function<T, U> mapper` represents a function taking an object of type `T` and returns a value of type `U`
- `Optional<U>` is an Optional encapsulating an object of type `U`.

You could visualize the mapper function as:

```
         _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
        |                 |
        |                 |
T ----->|      logic      | -----> U
        |                 |
        |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

So, given the above visualisation and your example of:

```
Optional<String> os1 = Optional.of("Optional String");
Optional<String> os2 = os1.map(s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

The function passed to the `map` method of the `Optional` type (`s -> s.toUpperCase()` ) is  `Function<String, String> mapper` i.e. `T` in the visualization above becomes `String` and `U` in the visualization above becomes `String` i.e.

```
             _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
            |                 |
            |                 |
  String -->|      logic      | ---> String
            |                 |
            |_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

So, when the above function is invoked by the `map` method of the Optional type, it will perform some operation represented by the "logic" above in the visualization, in this specific case the logic is simply converting the input string to an uppercase string.

Once that is done, the `map` method of the `Optional<T>` type wraps that uppercase string into an Optional object hence it returns an `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you have a wrong src (with Javadoc) project of you JDK. Consider what the [Oracle Docs about Optional in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) says:

> **map(Function mapper)**
>
> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and
>   if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result.